# We all love a good rebus puzzle!

Tags: word, rebus

Guess the common theme and solve these rebus puzzles.

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The theme is:

> Song titles

---

---

I think I have all the correct answers (giving credit where it's due):

1.

> [The Final Countdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Final_Countdown_(song)) (found by noedne)

2. 

> [Sweet Home Alabama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_Home_Alabama) (found by noedne)

3. 

> [Blowin' in the Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowin%27_in_the_Wind) (found by noedne/u_ndefined)

4. 

> [Bad to the Bone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_to_the_Bone)

5. 

> Wrong guess: [The Music in my Heart](https://www.elyrics.net/read/k/kami-lyrics/the-music-in-my-heart-lyrics.html)
>  Correct answer: [Heart of Rock and Roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Heart_of_Rock_%26_Roll) (found by curtisk)

6. 

> Wrong guess: [The Middle](https://genius.com/Zedd-the-middle-lyrics)
>  Correct answer: [It's Going Down for Real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.D.F.R._(song)) (found by cpcodes)

7. 

> [Fire and Ice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_and_Ice_(Pat_Benatar_song))

8. 

> Wrong guess: [24/8](https://open.spotify.com/track/1QxqhiY58vpNlOWvgDkS6e)
>  Correct answer: [Eight Days a Week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Days_a_Week) (found by curtisk)

9. 

> [Blank Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blank_Space) (found by noedne/u_ndefined)

10. 

> Wrong guess: [Stuck in a Rut](https://genius.com/The-darkness-stuck-in-a-rut-lyrics)
>  Correct answer: [Rolling in the Deep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_in_the_Deep) (found by Reversifer)

11. 

> [Who Let the Dogs Out?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Let_the_Dogs_Out%3F) (found by noedne)

Comment: I hope the common theme is a little less generic than that! But maybe :-(

Comment: 10 is not correct, curtisk got 8, and 5, we just need 6 and 10.

Comment: The theme is correct too :D

Comment: How about `around the world - Daft Punk` for 10?

Answer (score 4):

Partial answers:

> 1. The Final Countdown

> 2. Sweet Home Alabama

> 3. Blowing in the Wind

> 4. <s>Hands Down</s>

> 5. <s>With a Song in my Heart</s> <s>Rhythm of Love</s>

> 6.

> 7. Fire and Ice

> 8. <s>3</s>

> 9. Blank Space

> 10.

> 11. Who Let the Dogs Out?

Comment: 8 is also incorrect and 5.

Comment: For Number 8:  Think of a Beatles song about, quite frankly, *amazing* time-management.

Comment: For number 10, could it be `around the world - Daft Punk`?

Answer (score 3):

**PARTIAL ANSWER**

3.

> Blowing in the wind

4.

> Bad hands also has bad bones

5.

> Rhythm in love (wrong)

7.

> Fire and ice

9.

> Blank space

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie can you check it now?

Comment: You are close with #4. not #5.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie again?

Answer (score 2):

Partials: (Edit two new guesses on 6 and 10)

1)

> The Final Countdown

2)

> Sweet Home Alabama

3)

> Blowin' in the wind

4)

> Bad to the Bone

5)

> Heart of Rock and Roll / Groove is in the Heart

6)

> Middle of the Road

7)

> Fire and Ice

8)

> 8 Days a week

9)

> Blank Space

10)

> Circle the Drain / Circle in the Sand

11)

> Who let the Dogs out?

Comment: Heart of rock and roll is correct, and so are the rest :D, we just need 10 and 6.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie new guesses on 6 and 10

Comment: Nope sorry, I will provide a hint later if no one gets it. Great job on the ones so far ^-^

Answer (score 2):

10)

> 10 is rolling in the deep

6 has me stumped though

Comment: Yes you got it, Great Job. P.S. Welcome to puzzling stack exchange. Hope you stay ^-^

Comment: I will! Ive been lurking for awhile but i may be more active now!

Answer (score 2):

6)

> It's Going Down for Real - Flo Rida

Comment: Sorry not correct. Great try though ^-^

Comment: Updated with a new guess.

Comment: Yes great you solved the last puzzle. Great job ^-^

Answer (score 1):

Very partial answer :

10 might be

> back to earth from steve aoki

and 6

> lies, lies, lies from ministry

Comment: Sorry not correct, check out the new hints :D

Answer (score 1):

10.

> [Circle The Drain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJ8JZowhegI) by Katy Perry

Comment: Sorry not correct, check out the new hints :D